# Maven assembly: ear with additional resources in a zip

Tags: maven, packaging, maven-assembly-plugin, ear-file

I have a project that's made up out of an ear, some XSLT files, RNC schema files. I want to keep the XSLT, schema and document files external (for hot-replacement), and I want to package everything in a zip on release. Lets' name the project 'foo'. I have the following modules:

- `foo` (parent)
- `foo-jar` creates a jar file (with mbeans)
- `foo-war` creates war file
- `foo-ear` creates ear file, depends on jar and war

This is all working, but here are my questions:

- Where do the XSLT, schema and documentation files go? A separate module? inside the parent project?
- How and where do I create an assembly that bundles the ear file and the XSLT and schema directories in a zip?

Comment: Care to share your solution? I'd be interested to see what you were able to do at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) to define and create an assembly. This [thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Need-end-to-end-example-using-the-maven-assembly-plugin-td113264.html) may help with assembly configuration.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to but not succeeding, that's why I'm asking for help.